# Iframe Video starting on scroll stuck on

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, autoplay, onscroll

Im using wordpress ACF to embed a video in iframe on this site: [sofiajannok.com](https://sofiajannok.com)
The video starts when scrolling to video, the function itself works, and before it has been playing correctly, however now it gets stuck in a "loading loop". If you press the play button inside the iframe it plays instantly. Any ideas what the problems are?

php (iframe with options)

```
<div class="slide-content cf">  
        <?php
        $iframe = get_field('slide_video_oembed', $page_ID);
        if($iframe): ?>

        <div class="vid-fullscreen">
            <?php   
                // get iframe HTML


                // use preg_match to find iframe src
                preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);
                $src = $matches[1];


                // add extra params to iframe src
                $params = array(
                    'controls'    => 1,
                    'hd'        => 1,
                    'rel'   => 0,
                    'autoplay' => 0,
                );


                $new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
                $enableJS = '&enablejsapi=1';
                $new_src .= $enableJS;
                $iframe = str_replace($src, $new_src, $iframe);


                // add extra attributes to iframe html
                $attributes = 'allowfullscreen';

                $iframe = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $iframe);
                // echo $iframe
                echo $iframe;
                ?>
        </div>
        <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

JS-function:

```
/********************************************************  
        //AUTOPLAY IFRAME
        - Autoplay video when iFrame is in view, pause when not
    ********************************************************/
        play_i = 0; 
      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        jQuery("iframe").each( function() {
            $this = jQuery(this);
            _src = $this.attr('src');
            _ID = $this.attr('id');
            _yPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            _thisHT = $this.height();
            _thisTop = $this.offset().top;
            _thisBottom = _thisTop + _thisHT;



            if( _yPos > _thisTop*0.5 && _yPos < _thisBottom && play_i < 1) { //if iframe is in view
                $this[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*'); //play video
                play_i++;
            } else {     
                $this[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');   //pause video
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Video autoplay with sound was disabled on mobile devices for some time and recently this functionality started to get disabled on desktop browsers too. Web pages should not try to auto play videos without user interaction like "click to play".

Only solution is to forget about video autoplay and show "play" button to user so he can choose when to start playing video.

Comment: So autoplay doesn't even work with "muted" videos?

Also note that it starts only when Scroll to so this should work like a button right?

Comment: @CarlPapworth autoplay is supposed to work with muted videos but not always (depending on browser and user preferences).